# Authentication Using Firebase Auth and Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase Auth for Authentication in my Final Year Project. It was working just fine till now and since the past two days it's kinda misbehaving when I sign in the database doesn't respond sometimes and other times works just fine. Ok.. and when it's misbehaving like this I hot reload my app and it again works just fine. There are some other issues like when I upload pictures writing to a firestore database sometimes the spinner keeps loading and database doesn't respond and other times works perfect just like the authentication. I want to confirm is it because of my network connectivity because from the past two days when I started facing this issue my network is not stable. Some sites are completely off and not working and even when I post something on linkedIn etc it also takes a lot of time. Please anyone guide me as it is my Final Year Project I don't want it to be buggy if that's not a network problem. I'm attaching the authentication code below:

LogInScreen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import '../../controllers/auth_controllers.dart';
import '../../views/mobile_client/forget_password_screen.dart';
import '../../widgets/common widgets/role_based_navigator.dart';
import '../../widgets/common widgets/snack_bar.dart';
import '../mobile_client/signup_screen.dart';

import '../../utils/colors.dart';

class LogInScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LogInScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<LogInScreen> createState() => _LogInScreenState();
}

class _LogInScreenState extends State<LogInScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  bool isVisible = true;
  bool isLoading = false;

  void logInUser() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    if (_emailController.text.isEmpty || _passwordController.text.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
      customSnackBar('Please enter all the fields');
    } else {
      try {
        String res = await AuthControllers().logInUser(
            email: _emailController.text, password: _passwordController.text);
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
        });
        if (res != 'Success') {
          customSnackBar(res.toString());
        } else {
          setState(() {
            isLoading = false;
          });
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const RoleBasedNavigator()));
        }
      } catch (err) {
        print(err.toString());
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    _emailController.dispose();
    _passwordController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 50.sp),
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            'assets/images/Logo.png',
            height: 300.h,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 50.h,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: _emailController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Enter Your Email',
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
            ),
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.sp),
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: _passwordController,
            obscureText: isVisible,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter Your Password',
                prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.lock),
                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        isVisible = !isVisible;
                      });
                    },
                    icon: isVisible
                        ? const Icon(Icons.visibility_off)
                        : const Icon(Icons.visibility))),
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.sp),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20.h,
          ),
          InkWell(
            onTap: logInUser,
            child: Container(
              height: 50.h,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: primaryColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.sp)),
              ),
              child: Center(
                  child: isLoading
                      ? const CircularProgressIndicator(
                          color: secondaryColor,
                        )
                      : Text(
                          'Log In',
                          style:
                              TextStyle(color: secondaryColor, fontSize: 17.sp),
                        )),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10.h,
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(ForgetPasswordScreen.routeName);
              },
              child: Text(
                'Forgotten Password?',
                style: TextStyle(color: primaryColor, fontSize: 17.sp),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 250.h,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Don\'t have an Account?',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: accentColor,
                  fontSize: 17.sp,
                ),
              ),
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(SignUpScreen.routeName);
                },
                child: Text(
                  ' Sign Up',
                  style: TextStyle(color: primaryColor, fontSize: 17.sp),
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Auth Controller

```
import 'package:bcrypt/bcrypt.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import '../models/role_model.dart' as model;
import '../models/patient_model.dart' as model;
import '../models/doctor_model.dart' as model;

class AuthControllers {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  
  Future<String> logInUser(
      {required String email, required String password}) async {
    String res = 'Some Error Occured';
    try {
      if (email.isNotEmpty || password.isNotEmpty) {
        await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password);
        res = 'Success';
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        res = 'No user registered with this email';
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        res = 'Invalid Credentials';
      }
    } catch (err) {
      print(err.toString());
    }
    return res;
  }
}
```

I've tried running it on my Mobile phone.. however there were still the issues felt like network connectivity.